# Remove huge number of rows in chunks PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have a table with more than 77 milions of rows. Most of them (about 50 milions) I have to remove. I created the function which removes chunk of rows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cleanupItems(skipRowsNumber BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
DECLARE
    cur_ids CURSOR FOR SELECT id, event_id FROM someTable ORDER BY id limit 1000 offset skipRowsNumber;
    row RECORD;
    processed_count BIGINT;
BEGIN
    processed_count = 0;
    OPEN cur_ids;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_ids INTO row;

        IF row is null THEN
            exit;
        end if;

        delete from items
        where ref_id = row.id
          and event_id <> row.event_id;

        processed_count = processed_count + 1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_ids;

    RETURN processed_count;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then I call this function from outter loop:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    processed_count BIGINT;
    offsetRows BIGINT;
BEGIN
    offsetRows = 0;
    LOOP
        raise notice 'removing items starting from %', offsetRows;
        processed_count = cleanupItems(offsetRows);
        offsetRows = offsetRows + processed_count;
        EXIT WHEN processed_count = 0;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

However, this is extremelly slow (it takes more than 1 hour). At the very beginning it runs fast but more rows removed the calls become slower.

Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Doing that in a loop is the slowest way to do that. What about: `delete from items where ctid in (select ctid from items limit 1000);`

Comment: Do you mean outter loop? Then how can I increase the offset?

Comment: No loop at all, just the DELETE statement you don't really need an offset, just add the appropriate WHERE clause to the sub-select

Comment: I tried - slower than with looping

Comment: What is the point of doing it in chunks in the first place?  There are valid reasons, but without knowing the reason it  pretty hard to suggest a workaround.

Comment: I just wanted to have some info on how processing is working. Also, I read that after every function call the commit is done (but not sure about the last one)

Comment: It isn't committed implicitly, and there is no commit in the outer loop.  Anonymous DO blocks can commit (since V11) but yours isn't doing so.  Also, this is a pretty expensive way to get feedback.  You could at least write the inner function as a single statement, with a CTE which applies the limit then the deletion done with a join to that CTE.

Answer (score 2):

How about emptying and repopulating the table instead?  I think this is your logic:

```
create table temp_items as
    select i.*
    from items i 
    where exists (select 1 
                  from sometable s
                  where i.ref_id = s.id and i.event_id <> s.event_id
                 );

truncate table items;   -- back it up first!

insert into items
    select * from temp_items;
```

For the first query, you want an index on `sometable(id, event_id)`.

Comment: I tried but it is also very slow. There will be round about 25 millions of rows which should be inserted to temp table

Comment: @Adam . . . Slow.  But much faster than deleting individually from the original table.  Once the temporary table is created, you just need to empty and insert the rows.  These bulk operations are typically much faster than individual row operations.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it gets slower as it goes along describes just what you would expect with the loop with the ever increasing offset.  Postgres has no way to implement this offset efficiently, because as far as it knows some other session is adding, removing, or updating rows which will affect the offset computation.  So to do the LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 65000, it has to process 66000 rows, to ignore 65000 of them and actually use 1000 of the.  The total time needed to skip all these row, most of them repeatedly, is going to be proportional to square of the number of rows in someTable (which you didn't tell us).

If someTable.id is unique, then you could record and pass back to the outer DO the highest value of someTable.id seen, it could pass that back in again for the next loop.  Then you could make the cursor:

```
cur_ids CURSOR FOR SELECT id, event_id FROM someTable 
    where id>lastSeenId 
    ORDER BY id limit 1000;
```

Or if that is not convenient, you could increase the value for the LIMIT.  At some point, the constant factor applied to the N^2 term will then be small enough that the actual deletions will be slower than the overhead of repeatedly skipping rows.

Comment: In someTable there is just 250k rows. 77 millions of rows are in items table.

Comment: That seems slower than just the OFFSET would explain.  Do you have an index `on items(ref_id)`?  (although lack of one shouldn't make it get progressively slower, it would just be plain slow.